# Как в PyCharm задать путь к каталогу с тестами?

Tags: pycharm

В PyCharm есть одна очень удобная возможность - автоматическое создание тестов. Для любого метода любого класса можно из контекстного меню выбрать `Go to` > `Test` > `Create New Test...` и соответствующий тест создается в соответствующем классе в соответствующем модуле. Но одна проблема портит все. По умолчанию в качестве пути для создания модуля теста он выбирает тот же каталог, в котором находится тестируемый модуль. Поскольку тесты всегда лежат отдельно от остального кода, то приходится открывать диалог "Target directory" и задавать путь к каталогу с тестами каждый раз заново!

Вопрос: Как объяснить PyCharm что **все** мои тесты должны создаваться в определенном каталоге `./test` (от корня проекта), чтобы автосоздание новых тестов происходило одним (путь, двумя-тремя) нажатием клавиши.

Вместо этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Автоматически подставлять путь к `./test`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]